# Html Table format inconsistent while iterating loop in python?

Tags: python, html, css, wkhtmltopdf

Hi iam trying to convert htmlfile(contains table of data) into pdf using wkhtmltopdf. For one htmlfile it converts pdf looking good.  but when i call conversion code in while loop first page is good in pdf but next page onwards table stretch to next page.

Code is:

```
    html_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.html')  
    while curr_row < end:
        curr_row += 1
        row = { "CP_Ward" : worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, 17),
                  "CP_ParcelNo" : worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, 18),}

        html_file.write((html_rcc_string%(row["CP_Ward"],
                          row["CP_ParcelNo"],)).encode('utf8'))
    html_file.flush()
    pdf_file = htmltopdf([html_file.name])
    self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
    self.set_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.pdf")
    self.write(pdf_file.read())
```

In above code html_rcc_string contains  html code as python string as follows:

```
   <div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
    <table border=1>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Tax Rate Zone No.</td><td>Municipal Zone No.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>%s</td><td>%s</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    <table>
   </div>
```

In csstablegenerator.css :for table i give width and height values like below

```
      widht: 130%
      height: 100%
```

when I remove these things all pages in pdf are looking good. But table stretch in center of page.

According to my requirements i set these width and height to table tag

In While loop pdf first page looking good.but next page onwards table cells space are increasing and table placed in multiple pages.

I try with different css options but did not work for me

What mistake i done in loop.can you please give any suggestions.

Comment: just change css solve my problem .i change height:auto and widht:130

Answer (score 1):

Just changing the css solved my problem.

I changed `height:130` to `height:auto`.